# java spring boot with ldap authentication endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, ldap, backend, endpoint

i am working on a small web app, where i use vue js for the spa frontend application and i have already implemented a java spring boot app that provides some backend api endpoints.
For letting the users log in, i want to implement a login endpoint in java that tries to authenticate the users against the ldap server of the university..
For connecting to the ldap server i have the required configs. the server only tells me that the credentials are correct or not, so i can not get the recoreds of the users.
I saw a video on how to use ldap auth with spring boot and it worked, but the thing is that, the method used in the video secure all the routes/endpoints, but i need to secure only some of them.
The other problem is, a login form is returned to let user enter credentials, but i need to do this in the frontend app and only send the username and password to the server, so that the server generate a token and returns it to the spa..

for now i just need to return a response with "accepted" or "rejected".
can you please help me to implement that.

```
package de.thbingen.veg.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.BaseLdapPathContextSource;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.ldap.LdapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authManager(BaseLdapPathContextSource source) {
        LdapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory factory = new LdapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory(source);
        factory.setUserDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people");
        return factory.createAuthenticationManager();
    }

}
```

```
package de.thbingen.veg.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class LoginController {

    private final LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public LoginController(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate) {
        this.ldapTemplate = ldapTemplate;
    }
    //this is working, but not the way i want
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getHomePage() {
        return "hello!";
    }
    // this is not working as expected
    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public String authenticate(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
        try {

            boolean authenticated = ldapTemplate.authenticate(LdapUtils.emptyLdapName(),
                    "uid=" + request.getUsername() + ",ou=people",
                    request.getPassword());

            if (authenticated) {
                return "accepted";
            } else {
                return "rejected";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "error: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

}

class LoginRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    // Getters and setters

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

the application.properties file has two values as provided from the ldap server admin:

```
spring.ldap.urls, spring.ldap.base
```